# Multer uploads binary file with different name and no extension instead of original file

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

When I try to use the upload in multer, the file that is upload is binary(no csv extension) and give the filename a very random name anyone know why this would happen? 
Also, I am using Postman to send the POST request, if that helps.

I have tried to change the mimetype and the name of the upload config, still does not help.

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require('multer');

const router = express.Router();
const upload = multer({
dest: './uploads',
mimetype: 'text/csv'
})

router.post('/upload',upload.single('upload'),(res,req,next)=>{
});

module.exports = router;
```

I do not get any error messages, but the save file on the local machine has no extension and the name is for example is: **9958216fa970f07a2d2382e66fb77f05**

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully uploaded fie using below code use below code as for reference.

//middleware.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = (file) => {
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './uploads/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log("File Object",file);
            let ext = '';
            if(file.originalname.split('.').length >1 ){
                ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'));
            }
            console.log('ext', ext);
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ext)
        }
    })
    return multer({ storage: storage }).array(file);
}
module.exports = {
    upload
}
```

//file.route.js

```
const uploadMiddleware = require('../middleware/middleware');

fileRoutes.route('/imgUploadMiddleWare')
    .post([uploadMiddleware.upload('img'), fileValidation.checkFile], fileController.uploadFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multer is not storing the file in binary format. It just removes the extension and randomise the filename to avoid conflicts. If you would just append the right extension, you've got your file.

**For example**: Original file `hello.jpg` got stored as `9958216fa970f07a2d2382e66fb77f05`, just change its extension to `9958216fa970f07a2d2382e66fb77f05.jpg`.

**From the docs:** [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

> By default, Multer will rename the files so as to avoid naming conflicts. The renaming function `filename` can be customised according to your needs.
>
> Multer will not append any file extension for safety reasons, your function should return a filename complete with an file extension.

**How to achieve this programmatically: original name + extension**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    /*Appending extension with original name*/
    cb(null, file.originalname + path.extname(file.originalname)) 
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

- `path` is used to get extension of the file
- `file` object has `originalname` field to get it. Although I recommend another appended value like `file.originalname + Date.now()` to avoid name conflicts and achieve uniqueness to a level.

Comment: Yeah this was exactly right, but file.originalname gets the extension on its own so adding path.extname would store as image.png.png